# voronoi and lloyd relaxation using python/scipy

Tags: python, scipy, voronoi, qhull

How to determine, using Qhull, which voronoi cells (by index) are "proper" (made of "existing vertices")

I am trying to perform a constrained relaxation using LLoyds algorithm and input generated by scipy.spatial Voronoi (which is a wrapper for Qhull).

In terms of code it looks like:

```
points = [n  for n in itertools.product(xrange(3),xrange(3))]
vor = Voronoi(points)

vor2 = lloyd(vor) # my relaxation function  - not relevant to the question
```

The  output graph generated by the code  looks ok (see below)
but the data in the vor structure is not enough to perform the Lloyds relaxation.
It is because I should only move the points that are inside the valid voronoi cells ( #4 in the image). The other should be left as they are. Qhull messes the order of points/regions so I can not estimate which region belongs to which point.

Here is the illustration of the problem:

```
print vor.vertices
#[[ 0.5  0.5]
# [ 1.5  0.5]
# [ 0.5  1.5]
# [ 1.5  1.5]]

print vor.regions  
# [[], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [1, -1, 0], [3, -1, 2], [-1, 3], [-1, 2], [3, 2, 0, 1], [2, -1, 0], [3, -1, 1]]

print vor.points
# [[ 0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  1.]
#  [ 0.  2.]
#  [ 1.  0.]
#  [ 1.  1.]
#  [ 1.  2.]
#  [ 2.  0.]
#  [ 2.  1.]
#  [ 2.  2.]]
print vor.point_region
# [1 8 6 3 7 4 2 9 5]
```

Now i should find somehow that vor.regions[7] is a region that belongs to the point vor.points[4].
How to achieve this?

[image: Voronoi on 3x3 grid]

Comment: Where do you have the complete solution? With the accepted answer?

Comment: the answer below was clear enough to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `region` you know, a `point` you don't, and you know that `vor.point_region[point] == region`. For a single `region`, you can figure out the corresponding `point` as:

```
point = np.argwhere(vor.point_region == region)
```

You can also create a `region_point` indexing array to figure out multiple `points` from an array of `regions` as:

```
region_point = np.argsort(vor.point_region)
points = region_point[regions-1]
```

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand your answer but when I run the command suggested by you:
    np.argwhere(vor.point_region == 4)
the result is:
    array([[5]]) 
which is not correct. :(

Comment: That's because you should be running `np.argwhere(vor.point_region == 7)`. You know your region (7), it is the point (4) you are after, right? Because to get the region from the point you simply do `vor.point_region[4]`.